# Crediting a member account

Tags: civievent

A member completed the event registration process.  I need to adjust the registration dollar amount from $110 to $0.  I thought I would be able to do that from the financial record page but am having no success.  I also tried to do the credit from the event registration page but no luck.  How do I credit the amount to show the correct financials?  Thank you for any help you can give.
Sheryl Bacon
Ohio Society of Radiologic Technologists

Comment: Do you have permissions to Edit the financial record page?  If so, you can change the amount/status there.  Depending on your payment provider, you may have to initiate the credit with them to transfer the money back to the member.